# how to mock a constructor being initiated from inside a method with jest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mocking

i have a script that defines 2 classes, and 1 gets instantiated from within the constructor of the other. how can i mock the nested constructor, so i can test the parent constructor?

```js
export default class Foo {
  // i want to test this constructor...
  constructor() {
    new Bar
  }
}

export class Bar {
  // but mock this constructor
  constructor() {}
}
```

additionally, i am trying to spy on the Bar constructor, to assert that it has been called

i have tried several different approaches, but haven't been able to get the results i am looking for. i am new to the jest mocking library

Comment: Are these classes both in the same module? I read [this](https://medium.com/@DavideRama/mock-spy-exported-functions-within-a-single-module-in-jest-cdf2b61af642) recently, which suggests that you should separate them into different module files if you want to mock one and not the other.

Comment: A constructor is the same as a class that it represents. Literally, `Bar.prototype.constructor === Bar`. So that it's a constructor doesn't offer any opportunities regarding testing. You cannot mock a variable that is used in the same module where it was defined, end of the story. That Foo constructor contains side effect and ignores Bar instance is potentially an antipattern and should be addressed in the first place. If there were `this.bar = new Bar` you could assert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to make a little modification to the module export statement. Then, we can use [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) method to mock implementation for `Bar` class. Take a look at the [code](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAYhBHAN4BQccOEAdgTFOjjNABQCUVtdOI2AB3OKEiwCAOgBCqKLwDcAgL7V11PIWLyo_Og2at2nRXxqD6TAhEzBpmCAHMuAcijBUmOHuvG2Dmg4AEsAWzBMMOBGGFQYEKY3HhU6dU0JaBgZPwBeXwUlIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.12.3&externalPlugins=) after compiling. We create the mocked `Bar` in the module export object and we use it in the `Foo` class. It has the same reference as the mocked one.

Recommend way:

1. Dependency Injection
2. Each file contains ONLY ONE class. So that we can use `jest.mock` or `jest.doMock` method to mock the class without modifying the module export statement.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
export default class Foo {
  constructor() {
    new exports.Bar();
  }
}

class Bar {
  constructor() {
    console.log('real Bar constructor implmentation');
  }
}

exports.Bar = Bar;
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import * as mod from './';

console.log(mod);

describe('64549093', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const BarConstructorMock = jest.spyOn(mod as any, 'Bar').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      console.log('fake Bar constructor implmentation');
    });
    new mod.default();
    expect(BarConstructorMock).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64549093/index.test.ts (9.905s)
  64549093
    ✓ should pass (5ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/64549093/index.test.ts:3
    { default: [Function: Foo], Bar: [Function: Bar] }

  console.log src/stackoverflow/64549093/index.test.ts:8
    fake Bar constructor implmentation

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.751s, estimated 12s
```

About the configuration of `jestjs`, `TypeScript`, see example:
https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/64549093

Comment: this is incredibly helpful! not only does it help resolve my issue, but it helps me better understand jest. tyvm for taking the time to provide such clear & detailed info! :)

Comment: Original code contains only ESM, not CJS. It's a known workaround for this problem to use `exports` object but that ESM and CJS are mixed in the same module is a hack that smells bad.

Comment: @EstusFlask is this a reference to slideshowp2's 2nd bullet 'Each file contains ONLY ONE class'?

Comment: actually i found docs on the import syntax, but not using `mod as any` with jest.spyOn. using `jest.spyOn(mod, Bar)` seems to work as well, but what does adding `as any` do? is this just a typescript thing? or does it have meaning in js?

Comment: @brewster That's a reference to `new exports.Bar()` in the example. Having one module per class is the only reasonable solution here, not what the example shows. Yes, `as any` is TS thing. And it's unsafe to rely on `jest.spyOn(mod, Bar)` because modules are read-only by specs and they can really be read-only in Jest depending on the setup.

Comment: excellent... also, following your suggestion of a single class per file, exposed another issue. since i am not exporting Bar from the same file, and i am importing it instead, i can no longer import it and spy on it... how do i go about mocking a class that is imported in my script, but not imported in my test file?

Comment: @EstusFlask in addition to my last comment above, this solution stops working when i set `autoMock: true`. for some reason with automock, despite everything else the same, my assertions fail because `BarConstructorMock` is not called. any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: @brewster *how do i go about mocking a class that is imported in my script, but not imported in my test file?* - import it in test file then, just to be able to refer it. Don't use `autoMock: true`, it can screw things up with magic. It's unclear what your code looks like at this point. But you need to mock a module not with spyOn but with `jest.mock('...', () => ...)` - or with `jest.mock('...')` to automock it.

Comment: @EstusFlask good to know about autoMock... my instinct with testing is to start off restricted and whitelist what i need, vs the other way around. as far as jest.mock... if i try a straight across refactor from `jest.spyOn(mod, 'Bar').mockImplementation(() => {})` to `jest.mock(mod, 'Bar', () => {})`, i get the error `moduleName.split is not a function`. its not clear from the docs how to migrate from a spy to a mock... could you provide an example? and can you explain more on why to avoid using spyOn?

Comment: @brewster You shouldn't migrate because you shouldn't use spyOn for modules in the first place. Jest's recommended way is jest.mock. Most times jest.mock is used at top level, so it's automatically hoisted above `import`. Arguments are wrong, check jest.mock documentation, it also has the example on mocking of named export which has its quirks, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options . The reason why spyOn shouldn't be used for modules has been explained in my comment above.